# Event Monitor in DB2 log the details of query run from VPN on the same server where events are created?

Tags: database, db2

Events has been created on my database. If anybody take the VPN of my DB and do some tasks. These activities logged or not.If not then how we can do that.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to configure the Db2 audit facility

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005483.html

> The Db2 audit facility generates, and allows you to maintain, an audit trail for a series of predefined database events. The records generated from this facility are kept in an audit log file. The analysis of these records can reveal usage patterns that would identify system misuse. Once identified, actions can be taken to reduce or eliminate such system misuse.